# Xamarin OnIdiom and OnPlatform StaticResource For Margins

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm setting up a style for a label and having some issue with the XAML formatting. I have the below code which works well.

```
 <Style x:Key="LabelMargin" TargetType="Label">

             <Setter Property="Margin">
             <Setter.Value>
               <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                     <OnIdiom.Phone>5,5,0,0</OnIdiom.Phone>
                     <OnIdiom.Tablet>10,20,0,0</OnIdiom.Tablet>
                </OnIdiom>
           </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
</Style>
```

However, I like to be able to drill now a little more to the OS level.
Instead of just phone,  I like to target the OS.

I found some samples but none of them are for margins.
I have come up with the below XAML but its not working?

```
   <Style x:Key="LabelMargin" TargetType="Label">
     <Setter Property="Margin"  x:TypeArguments="Thickness" Value = "{OnIdiom 
         Phone= {OnPlatform iOS =5,5,0,0 , Android=5,5,0,0},
         Tablet= {OnPlatform iOS =5,5,0,0 , Android=5,5,0,0}}" >
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Mike

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error I got it to work. If anyone stumbles on this question here is how I got to to work:

```
<Setter Property="Margin"> 
             <Setter.Value>
                 <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                   <OnIdiom.Phone>
                      <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" Android ="5,5,0,0" iOS ="5,5,0,0"  />
                   </OnIdiom.Phone>
                    <OnIdiom.Tablet>
                      <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" Android ="20,20,20,20" iOS ="20,20,20,20"  />
                   </OnIdiom.Tablet>
                </OnIdiom>
           </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
```